# Do we need to cleanup downloaded image files?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7

In my iOS app I am downloading a bunch of image files and saving them on disk in Library/Caches. Do I need to delete those files given iOS automatically clears them when its running low on disk space.

Comment: where are you saving the files to disk?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends where you save them. Read the [File System Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html) for detailed discussion.

In Summary, If you are saving the files to:

- **Temp**: You don't need to worry about cleanup, but you need to be aware that these files will not persist between app launches
- **Library/Caches** Generally iOS won't delete these files but can clear them when running on low disk space. So developer has to make sure these files can be regenerated when required.
- **All other folders** yes, you need to make sure the files are properly cleaned up when they are no longer needed.

**UPDATE:** Now that you have specified that you are saving to *Library/Caches*, [From Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010672-CH2-SW1) about *Caches* directory:

> Use this directory to write any app-specific support files that your app can re-create easily. Your app is generally responsible for managing the contents of this directory and for adding and deleting files as needed.
>
> In iOS 2.2 and later, the contents of this directory are not backed up by iTunes. In addition, iTunes removes files in this directory during a full restoration of the device.
>
> On iOS 5.0 and later, the system may delete the Caches directory on rare occasions when the system is very low on disk space. This will never occur while an app is running. However, you should be aware that iTunes restore is not necessarily the only condition under which the Caches directory can be erased.

To be specific *Your app is generally responsible ... for adding and deleting files as needed.*, You should *always* clean up after yourself. If you know you are done with the files, keeping them on disk and waiting for the device to run on low disk space so that the OS deletes them is a bad idea.

btw, if you are downloading files from the internet, why don't you use an already build library (so that you don't have to worry about these things).

- If you are developing for iOS 8.0+ and using Swift, you could use [AlamofireImage](https://github.com/Alamofire/AlamofireImage) as an **embedded framework**. It comes with a very good caching system. I think you can use it on iOS 7 as well by copying the Swift files.
- If you are using Objective C, you could use [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) which comes with its own caching system. You could also use [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) and enable basic caching, [this blog post](http://www.overacker.me/blog/2015/01/12/image-caching-with-afnetworking) should get you started.